# Does a natural comparator exist in the standard api?

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I need a comparator as part of a strategy pattern that can either use the natural ordering of the objects or some custom ordering. For the natural ordering case, I wrote a simple comparator:

```
private static class NaturalComparator<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparator<T> {
    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
```

Seems simple enough, but I was wondering if anyone knew of one in the standard API. I looked at TreeMap, and it does it without such a class, so when that code was written, the apparent answer would be no, but perhaps it was added later.

Comment: Maybe worth a mention: OUTSIDE of the standard API, there is Guava's Ordering.natural().

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Added to [Comparator in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--):

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> naturalOrder()
```

Use it like this, for example:

```
Comparator<Double> natural = Comparator.<Double>naturalOrder();
return natural.compare(1.0, 1.1));
```

Comment: If you aren't using Java 8 yet, and you want to use the Comparator in something simple like `Arrays.sort()` or `Collections.sort()`, you can simply pass `null` to the Comparator argument, and it will use the natural order.  Not all uses of Comparator are guaranteed to work that way though.  At least for `Arrays` and `Collections`, it does work that way.

Comment: @Joe if using arrays, the class of the array items must implement the `Comparable` interface

Comment: Does `Comparator.<String>naturalOrder().compare(o1, o2)` supports alphanumeric?

Answer (score 54):

Yes, the JDK definitely has it!  Here it is:

`Collections.reverseOrder(Collections.reverseOrder())`

Just kidding.  (But it's true. (Just don't actually use that. (Ever.)))

Comment: I'm un-accepting this answer because it has been overcome by Java 8, but it is the right answer for pre-Java 8. But don't actually use it ;-).

Comment: I may be missing the joke here.  Why shouldn't I actually use it (in older Java)?  Nothing is really being reversed here.  The overhead is very modest.

Comment: @JirkaHanika, The most important thing - in the long run you - can do in coding is make the code comprehensible. Sure, this makes a nice one-liner and uses only API based classes, but the code in the question would be clear and obvious at a glance to any mid-level and up Java developer. This, like most any "trick" would create confusion for anyone who came along and read it later.

Comment: @Yishai - OK, I get your point, it's perhaps the easiest natural comparator in the old API, but I can implement a better one myself with the API, equally trivially using `compareTo`.  Thank you.

Comment: ```Comparator<String> reverseOrder = Collections.reverseOrder();
        Comparator<String> naturalOrder = Collections.reverseOrder(reverseOrder);```
seems comprehensible enough to me

Answer (score 10):

JDK does not have it, however it is called **ComparableComparator** and it exists in many frameworks such as [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/util/comparator/ComparableComparator.html), [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparableComparator.html), [Hibernate](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.1.GA/hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA-javadoc.jar!/org/hibernate/util/ComparableComparator.html) and many others

Comment: FYI, Guava calls it `Ordering.natural()`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with a default comparator in Java, but obviously, Comparator to compareTo is often a mere wrapper.

There is no general of "natural ordering" in the standard API, although certain built in types, like numbers, have an implementation of compareTo which then becomes their natural ordering.

`TreeMap` and `TreeSet` and all these should throw a RuntimeException if the object you put in does not implement Comparable. Thus, for example, you could throw in strings or numbers but not another collection.

The code of `TreeMap` does not use a comparator if one is not available - it uses `compareTo` instead. To use `compareTo`, it does a cast to `Comparable`, which is the source of the exceptions.

```
    private int compare(K k1, K k2) {
      return (comparator==null ? ((Comparable <K>)k1).compareTo(k2)
                                : comparator.compare((K)k1, (K)k2));
  }
```

Comment: by the way, in Java the Comparable implementation is called the Natural Ordering: http://www.filigris.com/products/docflex_javadoc/examples/new/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29

Comment: @Yishai: Ah. I was not aware of that. I would have assumed Java avoids the term like fire because compareTo could be have an arbitrary ordering that may not match the mathematical natural ordering or any ordering in the source domain. (e.g., the ordering of strings is not "natural" in the sense that it is not a pure natural language order)

Answer (score 2):

I think if a class has a natural ordering, it is more usual in Java for it to implement `Comparable` rather than have a `Comparator` implementation for each class.

Thus, if the objects in question have a natural ordering defined, they must implement `Comparable` and have the `compareTo` method defined. No need to go looking for a `Comparator`. Most classes in java.util take either an optional `Comparator` if there is any specific ordering to be imposed, or simply try to call `compareTo` on the objects if there is no other ordering specified.

So, long story short: Implement `Comparable` whenever you want to impose a natural ordering on a class, only use a `Comparator` when you want something other than the natural ordering.

Comment: @downvoter: Please explain the reason for a downvote. It is quite possible I made a mistake or am plain wrong, but it does not help if I (or the OP) don't know what it is.

Comment: MAK, although I didn't downvote, I didn't upvote either because it evades the question. Sometimes you want a class to sort based on the strategy pattern (in my case it is a sub-sort of a larger alpha-numeric sort), so you don't want a separate code path for natural ordering (TreeMap's code is quite ugly due to not doing this, although they may have had performance reasons for doing what they did).

Comment: I definitely agree about downvoting without a comment, though.

Comment: @Yishai: Point taken. So, what I'm saying is: no, there is no default `Comparator` in the Colections classes - because of the reasons stated in my answer. You have to roll your own if you feel the need for it.