# Case sensitive order for Strings

Tags: java, string

There is a `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` but why is there no `String.CASE_SENSITIVE_ORDER`? Or is there such an order somewhere hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Case-sensitive ordering is the default; i.e. [`String#compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) is case-sensitive. Therefore, there is no explicit `Comparator` for it.

```
Collections.sort(myStringList);  // case sensitive ("natural ordering")

Collections.sort(myStringList, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);  // case insensitive
```

Comment: Is this default comparator extractable?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain In Java 8, yes, using [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--). Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241063/does-a-natural-comparator-exist-in-the-standard-api) will be of interest to you as well.

Comment: Most things default to the natural ordering without you having to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Because String.CASE_SENSITIVE_ORDER is by default